# Populate INSERT with Result from SELECT

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to post username/password to a PHP file so I can use `inner join` to use those details to get the *uid* - (user id) from the *user* table. I use as the identifier for the *payid* table in a `WHERE` clause in an `INSERT` command. It's not working. Could someone advise where I am going wrong?

```
if(isset($_POST['password']) && isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['rates'])) {              
         $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
         if (!$con) {
            die ("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
            } else{
            mysql_select_db("council", $con); 
            $result = mysql_query('SELECT pid FROM payid INNER JOIN user ON user.uid = payid.uid WHERE user.username = " $_POST[username]" AND user.password =" $_POST[password] "');
            $pid = $result['pid'];
            if(isset($pid))
                $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO fees (rates, pid) VALUES ('$rates',  '$pid')");
                if(!$row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {    
                echo "<div id='t'>Invalid details please try again - use back arrow to return to form. </div>";
                                header ("Location: domRates.html");
                                }   
            if($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            header ("Location: services.html");
            }
        }
mysql_close($con);
```

Comment: http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/exploits_of_a_mom.png Just to pre-empt boring mysqli sermon, he can use whatever functions he likes

Comment: Well, first, you haven't told us what the problem is. "It doesn't work" doesn't tell us anything. Second, @imulsion's link highlights the fact you have no sanitation on your data, meaning it's trivial to perform SQL injection and end your database. Please format your code and tell us exactly what the problem is.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ). In attentional your PHP code is open for SQL injections.

Comment: @rekire did you see my comment?

Comment: @dKen I love that comic ;)

Comment: @imulsion I did but my comment contains also some references which are missing in your comment and you encoding the risk for a sql injection with a comic is not really helpful.

Comment: @rekire firstly, the comic portrays the message perfectly well, and secondly my comment pre-empts people posting a copied and pasted comment about the horror of mysql* functions. I see that exact comment on every mysql post that uses that family of functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
$query = "SELECT `pid` FROM `payid` INNER JOIN `user` ON `user`.`uid` = `payid`.`uid` WHERE `user`.`username` = '".$username."' AND `user`.`password` = '".$pass."'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
```

It is a good idea to wrap column names in backticks. When putting PHP variables into the query, open single quotes then concatenate with double quotes.

Comment: I cannot belive it you point to the sql injection but don't fix it. anyway if you add that IMHO useless `\``  `\`user.uid\`` should be written as `\`user\`.\`uid\`` or not?

Comment: @rekire since the injection was already mentioned, I did not post it. _useless `_? WTF? How on earth is that useless in any way?

Comment: In my personal opinion there is no reason in this case for them. I personally remove them everytime. However they are not wrong. I can only speak for me, but about the sql injection I would add at least a hint in the answer itself I don't read all comments to a question which is relevent for me.

Comment: I second that answers are distinct from comments. The answer should be self contained.

Comment: @rekire as you wish, I shall add an sql injection prevention piece of code. I tend to use backticks to make sure that it is always correct

Comment: Thanks for your input - your answers will be right - my question was wrong though as the damn thing still is returning     
Notice: Undefined index: username in J:\DynanicWeb_SM\EasyPHP-12.1\www\council\ratesform.php on line 2

Notice: Undefined index: password in J:\DynanicWeb_SM\EasyPHP-12.1\www\council\ratesform.php on line 3

Notice: Undefined index: rates in J:\DynanicWeb_SM\EasyPHP-12.1\www\council\ratesform.php on line 4
welcome - (this is my echo statement trying to pass back the $result in "Welcome " . $result . "")

Comment: @user2464423 that means the values are not getting passed to $_POST on the previous page. If i've helped, please consider accepting my answer (the green tick under the upvote/downvote count)

Comment: I tried to see if this was the case by using the get method to see if the details were passed in the browser bar and they were - I think it might be the fact that I am using jquery mobile that could be causing the problem .. any ideas

Answer (score 0):

I think your query statement is bad written.

try this:

```
$result =  mysql_query('SELECT pid FROM payid INNER JOIN user ON user.uid = payid.uid WHERE user.username = \'$_POST["username"]\' AND user.password =\'$_POST["password"]\'');
```

OR this:

```
$result =  mysql_query("SELECT pid FROM payid INNER JOIN user ON user.uid = payid.uid WHERE user.username = '". $_POST["username"]. "' AND user.password ='" . $_POST["password"]. "'");
```

Also your second query (INSERT) has to be modified by removing single quotes. Because fields "rates" and "pid" are not varchar or text. They should be number (int or double):

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO fees (rates, pid) VALUES ($rates,  $pid)");
```

Eventhough those two queries work, they are vulnerable for SQL injection. Also mysql_ is deprecated.

Comment: Ok - I guess I should have explained further - I kept getting errors so stripped the code back to basics - no prevention etc to try and identify what was not functioning correctly

Answer (score 0):

As this issue may be of some relevance to you here is how the thing works - as I said my issue as identified by others was mainly due to the fact that the _post info was not being transmitted through to the $_post variable no fault in coding so I altered it to $_REQUEST and hey presto - works - simplze:-)

```
<?php 
$username = sanitizeMySQL($_REQUEST['username']);
$pass = sanitizeMySQL($_REQUEST['password']);
$rates = sanitizeMySQL($_REQUEST['rates']);

function sanitizeString($var){
    $var = htmlentities($var);
    $var = strip_tags($var);
    return $var;
}

function sanitizeMySQL($var) {
    $var =  mysql_real_escape_string($var);
    $var = sanitizeString($var);
    return $var;
}

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
         if (!$con) {
            die ("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
            } else{

mysql_select_db("council", $con); 

$query = "SELECT * FROM `payid` INNER JOIN `user` ON `user`.`uid` = `payid`.`uid` WHERE `user`.`username` = '". $username . "' AND `user`.`password` = '" . $pass ."'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die(mysql_error());
$pid =  $row['pid'];
if (isset($result)) {
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `fees` (rates, pid) VALUES    ($rates,  $pid)");
header ("Location: acc.html");

    }
```